# Powershell move files with special characters

Tags: powershell

How can I move a file with special characters in it?  I am not allowed to rename the file.

My file is: File.Server.Windows.2003.[SP2].01232005.txt

```
# dFold = The destination folder in the format of \\drive\folder\SubFolder\   
# tDir = Root Target Directory on NAS
# sFold = The name of the subfolder that the files will go into
$dFold = "$tDir$sFold"

# sDir = Source Directory
# $File = Original file name as seen in the source Directory
Move-Item -Path $sDir$File -Destination $dFold -force
```

When I try to execute the above code it does not move the file.  I can add some Write-Host statements and it says it moves the file, but it really don't.

```
Write-Host "Now moving " $File "to " $dFold"\"
  Move-Item -Path $sDir$File -Destination $dFold -force

  # Now we just write put what went where or not          
  Write-Host $File "Was Moved to:" $dFold
```

Output:

```
Now moving  File.Server.Windows.2003.[SP2].01232005.txt to  \\NAS\Inventory\Servers\  
File.Server.Windows.2003.[SP2].01232005.txt Was Moved to: \\NAS\Inventory\Servers
```

Comment: Someone posted the answer, but then deleted it.  Changing Move-Item -Path to Move-Item -LiteralPath worked.  Whom ever you were, I thank you!

Comment: Yes I undeleted it. I wanted to verify it first :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try:

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath $sDir$File -Destination $dFold
```

[`Move-Item`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849852.aspx) allows [wildcard matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when using the `-Path` parameter, so a substring `[SP2]` is interpreted as a single character `'S'`, `'P'`, or `'2'` instead of the string `'[SP2]'`. Using the parameter `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` prevents that.

Comment: Path escaping is one of those things, for which the pitfalls bites so many of us.. 99% of the time, I don't need / want the escaping.. so better to be in a habit of always using `-LiteralPath`.